# Load Multiple Child Components using angular 2

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, angular2-services

I have a requirement wherein I call an external API to get a list of Ids for my child components and for each Id, I go out another external API to fetch the details of the child.

My Angular code in the parent component looks like this

```
 <div *ngFor="let link of result | objToArr">
        <details #Details [Id]="link.id"></details>
</div>
```

The result is the result I get from the first API cal and in the child component the [Id] above is an Input variable. I call the details API call on ngInit of the child component. Something similar to

```
                this.Service.getDetails(this.apiBaseUrl, this.Id).subscribe(
                    res => {
                        this.result = res.json().detail;
                        this.units = this.result.unit;
                        this.meterIdonLoad = this.Id;
                    });
```

This works for the most part, but there are multiple calls going out at the same time to fetch the details and the browser queues up the calls resulting in a rather unacceptable wait period for the whole page to load. Below is the network logistics for a single call. 
[image: Network Log from Chrome].

Is there a Better way to improve response times for the page/redesign the page ?

The individual calls through postman for the dtails takes anywhere from 50-80 ms, so the problem is not with the API server.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to show all of the details at the same time? You could fire a call each time the detail is shown and cache the result. If you have to show them all at the same time, you might consider passing all of the `link.id` values into a single endpoint and refactor your component to iterate over the data returned. Just a couple of ideas... there are always options.

Comment: Yes, will have to show the details at the same time. I guess i didnt mention that these are items in the grid. each line item in the grid is a child component. Firing multiple calls from API end better that multiple calls from UI ? I can write a wrapper over the external API and feed the dataset to the UI with all the data. Do you think that would improve load times ?

Comment: I would get all of the data at one time and then iterate over it. Angular is quite fast at rendering data. You can always show a loader to let the end user know something is going on to improve the user experience should the API call take a couple of seconds.

Comment: Let me give that a shot :). thanks for the help.

Comment: You bet. Always glad to help.

Comment: down to 4.96 secs from 22 seconds lol. I can live with that :).  I think I might cache it too.

Comment: I'd say that's a bit of an improvement :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your design based on your requirement

1) if your requirement is have all child details while loading page than your backed should handle the operation.

2) if your requirement is you can show some child details and reaming details once user started scrolling than you can use virtual scroll (https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll)

3) if your requirement is you need show user detail after selecting child component than you can fire each individual request after select operation.